# C++: How to make function return only strings which are a part of a list?

Tags: c++, types, enums

I want my function to return a string, but only strings which are a member of a specific list/set of strings. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Why do you need the enum to be strings in 1st place? If you want to display the values, provide a simple function to map those values to readable strings.And in fact you could use a `std::map<CardType,std::string>` to make that as easy as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Hoe about using a `std::set<std::string>`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

std::string helper(const std::string & str,
                   const std::set<std::string> & lst)
{
    return lst.find(str) == lst.end() ? "" : str;
}

int main()
{
    std::set<std::string> lst = {"alpha", "beta", "gamma"};
    std::cout << "return " << helper("alpha", lst) << "\n";
    std::cout << "return " << helper("zeta", lst) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
return alpha
return
```

---

Of course, it really depends on what your definition of **does not return** is.

If it means an empty string, then use the above solution. Keep your life simple.

If it means an error and the program should terminate, you may `#include <cassert>` and just

```
assert(lst.find(str) != lst.end());
```

If it means an exception to handle, you may `try` `throw` and `catch`.

If it means returning a `std::string` if `str` is in a predefined list, but a `void` if it's not, then you may need some tricks as described in `<type_traits>`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to return a string, you want to return a string that has an additional restriction (being part of some predefined set).

For that you'd need a new type:

```
class BusinessStringWrapper {
public:
  BusinessStringWrapper(std::string arg): value{arg} {
    if (/* arg is not ok */) {
      throw;
    }
  }
  // you can replace that with factory method
  // can also return std::optional instead of throwing if the condition is not met
  // that depends on your application

  std::string value() const { return value; }

private:
  const std::string value;
};
```

And in your application you'd operate on this type, accessing value if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this `std::map<CardType, std::string>` in the example below, or use `std::map<int, std::string>` to associate a string with any integer. For example `mp[123]="abcd"`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

enum CardType {
    SPADE,
    HEART,
    CLUBS,
    DIAMD
};

std::map<CardType, std::string> mp{ 
    {CardType::SPADE, "Spade"},
    {CardType::HEART, "Heart"},
    {CardType::CLUBS, "Clubs"},
    {CardType::DIAMD, "Diamond"}
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << mp[CardType::SPADE] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```